# Remote Desktop audio desync

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, audio, remote-desktop

I have a pretty simple problem, I do the opposite of most people - I remote home while at work (I really don't like the software environment at work). Everything works fine except the audio lags by about 3 seconds (video lags by like 30ms I'm guessing). Sometimes the audio will be synced but then the whole setup will lag a bit - the video will jump to the current spot but the audio will stay delayed. Even if I let it idle, it doesn't 'catch up'. I'm not playing games or anything, but I do some work with audio files for work and it can be frustrating trying to scrub through with such a delay. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks a bunch!

Setup:
HOME : 125mbps down 10 mbps up. WIN 10 Pro
WORK : 100mbps down 100 mbps up. WIN 7 Pro

I have a 3 monitor setup but again - not heavy on the video, mostly static images.

Comment: I think it's inherent in the RDP audio protocol: that the audio buffers have a fixed large size, so it will always lag behind video. That said, have you tried using third-party RDP clients (clients that use their own RDP implementation, not those that just wrap the RDP ActiveX control)?

Comment: @Dai Not necessarily correct - I've worked with Video over IP systems using RDP where there was no lag between video and audio.

Comment: I just tried teamviewer and it was in sync but there was more latency overall. My guess is RDP prioritizes the video stream and has a good amount of optimizations to make the video moderately lightweight (which it doesn't do with the audio) whereas teamviewer just turns it all into a video and sends it.

Comment: Having the same problem with a newer computer and on LAN. Definitely seems to be an issue with RDP.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you wanted and is very hacky - but I got it working and is definitely better than 3 seconds of delay

Use [SoundWire](http://georgielabs.net/).
It's a freemium software that broadcasts your system sounds to android device.
Download and install server on Windows, launch client on android phone or [use android emulator](https://secabit.medium.com/how-to-run-android-emulator-without-android-studio-88a3bb1d80eb).

If you purchase the premium version, you can set buffer size to very low for example 100ms. And set "Latency steering amount" to tight. Resulting latency might fluctuate between 80ms and 130ms. I used it with bluetooth headphones so end to end latency becomes something like 100ms(SoundWire) + 200ms(BT SBC) + some overhead by server and client.

For me, this reduced the audio lag to roughly .5 sec from 1 sec before.

Comment: https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/vban.htm seems to be better alternative